# Assigning existing geometry to another layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, merge

I have several line layers that run parallel to each other and would like to assign the geometry of the central line to all the others without losing information in the attribute tables.

Is there a way to automatically move all lines towards the position of my central line?

[image: I would like to move all lines to the position of the bold pink line automatically]

Comment: There is a tool in the processing toolbox called "snap geometries to layer" that sounds like it would do what you want.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help. I won't post that as an answer because I haven't used that tool before and can't provide any details. So feel free to post an answer to your own question, if you want to help other users of the site.

Answer (score 2):

According to csk's comment to my question, I tried using "snap geometries to layer" from the processing toolbox. This worked just the way I wanted and snapped all parallel lines to the central line.
With this feature, you can choose the layer you wish to snap to another geometry, choose a layer as reference layer to which the other layers shall be snapped, choose a tolerance of layer units and define the mode with which the geometries should be snapped. I wanted to have the programme add additional nodes wherever necessary, which led to the desired result.